# Issue in saving contacts to android - code attached

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-widget

I am trying to save the contact details to the android contacts through my application. I do not want to have the default contact application to do this job, instead I need to do this from my code directly. Here is the code which I use. After the button onclick, I would require to have the contact detail stored to the cntact in android, which, unfortunately is not happening.

Can someone please guide me where I am going wrong in this code and what need to be done in order to resolve the issue.

Any help in this regard is well appreciated.

Regards,
Rony

```
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(Phone.NUMBER, "456456");
            values.put(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_WORK);
            Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(Phone.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Comment: What affect are you seeing?  An exception, or nothing happens?  What uri is returned?  How are you testing that it is not being saved?

Comment: The details of the exception I have posted here  http://pastebin.com/L5AvbLRK

Comment: please do not leave this unresolved..experts please guide

Comment: You only asked this 2 hours (before you posted your last message). No one wants to follow a pastebin link. Post what your error is, what you're seeing, what you're expecting and maybe we can help.

Answer (score 1):

I look for a solution for this problem and I found this.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html

There are examples there for any kind of operations. This is the insert example.

```
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
 values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
 values.put(Phone.NUMBER, "1-800-GOOG-411");
 values.put(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM);
 values.put(Phone.LABEL, "free directory assistance");
 Uri dataUri = getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

I hope it helps you.